# asp.net GridView Pager disappears!

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging

I have a datagridview that is using paging, it works perfectly fine and I have a drop down that allows the user to change the 'PageSize' property - 10, 15, 25, 50, 100, 1000 etc.

When I select a value for the PageSize that is greater than the row count for the grid the Pager is disappearing from both the top & bottom of the grid.

Anyone got any ideas why?

I'm using a custom PageTemplate element in the aspx page.

Cheers

Ollie

Comment: Ollie, Consider retagging this.  It is a GridView on the ASP.NET side and a DataGridView on the Windows side.

Comment: Isn't this normal behaviour? When you don't need paging why the pager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Behaviour is by design. You can force it to remain visible by setting the Visible property of the pager row (accessed using either TopPagerRow or BottomPagerRow property) in the grid's OnDataBound event. For example:

```
protected void grid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grid.TopPagerRow.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that this happens if you are trying to force a column to be invisible.
for example if you use:

e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;

You can cause the pager to render invisible.

You should use this code instead:

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{ 
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}

Answer (score 0):

When the number of pages is one, there is no need to show Next/Previous or other pages.  Sounds like normal behavior to me.

Comment: it's no good if I want to dynamically change the number of rows displayed by a drop down in the pager...

But there again I shouldn't really allow the user to change the number of rows displayed in the pager that's just a stupid requirement...

Answer (score 0):

the Issue is Related to Design so Please Go to The Properties of Rad Grid View and Just Change The Property :  Style-->PagerStyle-->AlwaysVisible To (True)

Comment: The question is not about RadGrid but asp gridView!

Answer (score 0):

Verify the GridView.VirtualItemCount
Sometimes after update DataSource this value is not the same.
For Exemple: First time => 100 and in the next time you set a different value to the same database query.

http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20060109.asp